# Send $forum_id when submit

Tags: php, html, forms, phpbb3

I have created an script , and I want to use to replace `posting.php` with it on phpbb3

The script its a form, with `action="application"`

When i click on "new topic" i have redirected to `submit.php?mode=post&f=3` instead of `posting.php?mode=post&f=3`

and then in submit.php I have and html with fields, and a submit button

The problem is that when performs the `action="application.php"` I need to give the forum id to that php when click on submit.

any ideas?

UPdaTE

this is my app.html:

```
<!-- INCLUDE overall_header.html -->
    <!-- <h2> Form Submission </h2>
      <div class="panel">
      <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span> -->
        <form  method="post" action="application.php" accept-charset="utf-8" >
            $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['f']);
            <input type="hidden" name="forum_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
            <span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
            <label>Agregar Url De La Pelicula</label><br>
            <input id="link" name="link" type="text" value="http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film628461.html" size="100" maxlength="100">
            <fieldset class="submit-buttons">
                <input value="Submit" class="button2" type="submit">
           </fieldset>

       </form>

     <!-- <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
   </div> -->
      <!-- INCLUDE overall_footer.html -->
```

this is my submit.php:

http://pastebin.com/unjSNwMT

and this my application.php:

Comment: Put the forum id into a hidden field in the first form …

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fourm_id", value="<?php echo $_GET['f']; ?>"/>
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: when i put that into html file in form section, what i have to put into application.php? something like : $forum_id = request_var('forum_id', ''); ? because when trying it i get an error "The forum you selected does not exist." and in the address bar i get "viewforum.php?f=&sid=a69fb9f491d2adc11c4be3a6dac02774" what is the problem?

Comment: Update. You will want to sanitize that info.